# How to get metadata of source DB using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, metadata, hive, sqoop

Sqoop reads the metadata of the source DB before storing the data into HDFS/HIVE.

Is there any method by which we can get this metadata information from sqoop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question:

To get the metadata from sqoop , we can use the sqoop java apis and connect to the destination and get the following metadata

1. Table name
2. Db name
3. Column details etc.